# ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer with proxy

Tags: javascript, dictionary, proxy, arcgis, esri

We have an url based `ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer` that we need to use a proxy to access. 
Where and how are we supposed to use the proxy with it?

```
var basemap = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("http://maps.blabla.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set proxy rule for your url with the [`"esri/urlUtils"`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/esri.urlutils-amd.html) module.

```
require(["esri/urlUtils"], function(urlUtils) {
    urlUtils.addProxyRule({
        urlPrefix: "maps.blabla.com",
        proxyUrl: "<url_to_proxy>"
    });
});
```

For more information: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/ags_proxy.html